# does exception-pattern work on commit-transaction?

Tags: mule

Does the `exception-pattern` attribute on the `commit-transaction` tag work? That is, in a default exception strategy I can get this to work,

```
<commit-transaction exception-pattern="*"/>
```

but not this:

```
<commit-transaction exception-pattern="some.specific.Exception"/>
```

Here is a relevant snippet of the configuration:

```
<mule ...>
    <jms:activemq-connector name="JMSConnector" brokerURL="${messaging.brokerURL}" />
    <flow name="aFlow">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint name="endpoint.Name" queue="${queue}"
                              exchange-pattern="request-response"
                              connector-ref="JMSConnector" />
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="ThrowsBusinessException" />
        </component>

        <default-exception-strategy>
            <commit-transaction exception-pattern="com.BusinessException" />
        </default-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

If I use `exception-pattern="*"`, the JMS message is not re-delivered. However, if I use the more specific `exception-pattern`, the message is re-delivered. I don't want the message to be re-delivered if the exception thrown is `BusinessException`.

This is in Mule CE 3.2.1

Thanks!

Comment: Mule version? Error received?

Comment: @David: More details in the message now.

Comment: Side note: you want `specification="1.1"` on your ActiveMQ connector.

Comment: Also I assume that you have `<jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" /> ` inside the `jms:inbound-endpoint` otherwise no transaction will start. I had to add that in order to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @David: Odd. the `<commit-transaction exception-pattern='*' />` works even if I do not begin the transaction inside the jms inbound endpoint. Also, thanks for the note about the `specification` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue is the following: all exceptions thrown by a component are wrapped in a `org.mule.component.ComponentException`.

`default-exception-strategy` used to but now fails to unwrap this exception to its root cause, which means the `exception-pattern` gets applied to the `org.mule.component.ComponentException`.

IMO this is a bug in Mule. I've opened [MULE-6218](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6218). Please vote for/watch it.

In the meantime, you can create a custom exception strategy that unwraps the Mule exceptions before to handling them. For this, use: `ExceptionHelper.getRootException(ex)`

Comment: could you give an example of how to "swallow" an exception (i.e. consider the processing to be completed) in a custom exception strategy if the exception is of a certain type?

Comment: Extend AbstractExceptionStrategy and override isRollback() to control simulate this behavior.

Comment: It couldn't be simpler. Thanks.

Comment: there seems to be an issue with the jms response when I extend `AbstractExceptionStrategy` (the inbound jms endpoint has request-response exchange pattern. I missed that in my original post -fixed now) The jms response may not be sent to the caller! The caller seems to be timing out after 10 seconds waiting for the response ...

Comment: Is the transaction committed? What code do you use for the caller? Sounds like a different issue... new question maybe?